# define vim key mapping for user defined bash function

Tags: bash, scripts, vim, bashrc

I defined a bash function in my .bashrc file, "myfun" for example.
Now I would like to execute this function inside vim

```
function vimfun(filename) 
    execute '!myfun' '%' 
endfunction
```

and I want to map this function to a vim key map below:

```
autocmd FileType bla nmap <buffer> <LocalLeader>pp :let a=@% <CR>:call vimfun(a)<CR>
```

However, it complained could not find command myfun when I execute the function. 
I added execute 'source ~/.bashrc' but it generate even more error.

Any solution to let bash find the user defined function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that as @dessert suggested, using `execute '!bash -ic "myfun %"'` works.